# C# Windows Form App: cast/assign user-defined type when tab is changed

Tags: c#, forms, types, casting

I'm building a Windows Form App in C# with functionality broken into various named tabs. I'd like to set the type of an object based on which tab is selected. Types which can be assigned are classes which I have defined, i.e. Type1, Type2...
For example:

```
//resides in Form class code
public object currObject;
...
private void TabPage_SelectedIndexChanged (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
//set currObject type to Type1 if 1st tab was selected
//otherwise Type2
}
```

What is the most elegant and efficient way to achieve this? Reinstantiating the object inside each method seems extremely wasteful, so I'd much prefer any form of type assignment occur inside the `_SelectedIndexChanged` event handler.

Comment: Apply your OOP knowledge, via using `Interface`. Each `Type` will implement that `Interface`. Or via inheritance.

Comment: Good point. I had honestly hoped there was a mechanism in C# that would allow me to do this in a simpler fashion(similar to what I described), but in the long run using a common interface might be a better idea.

Answer (score 0):

Do it like:

```
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            tabControl1.SelectedIndex = 1;
        }

        private void tabControl1_Selected(object sender, TabControlEventArgs e)
        {
             currObject = tabControl1.SelectedTab == tabControl1.TabPages["tabPage1"] ? "type1" : "type2";
        }
```

if you want to set the first tab as your `Default` with a value of `currObject` on Form_Load event.

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            tabControl1.SelectedIndex = 1;
            tabControl1.SelectedIndex = 0;

        }
```

Comment: I appreciate the feedback, however the "?" operator won't work here. I was using Type1 and Type2 as examples, but in the actual code there will be 1 to n different tabs with corresponding types.